# Multi-Threading & Google App Engine Servlets

Tags: java, multithreading, google-app-engine

On Google App Engine (GAE) it is possible for frontend instances to create up to 10 threads to maximize throughput. According to [this page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime#The_Sandbox), such multi-threading can be accomplished as follows:

```
Runnable myTask = new Runnable({
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do whatever
    }
});

ThreadFactory threadFactory = ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory();

// GAE caps frontend instances to 10 worker threads per instance.
threadFactory.newRequestThread(myTask);
```

To hit my GAE server-side, I'll expose many servlets mapped to certain URLs, such as the `FizzServlet` mapped to `http://myapp.com/fizz`:

```
public class FizzServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        // Handle the request here. Somehow send it to an available
        // worker thread.
    }
}
```

**I guess I'm choking on how to connect these two ideas.** As far as I see it, you have 3 different mechanisms/items here:

1. The App Engine instance itself, whose lifecycle I can "hook" by implementing a `ServletContextListener` and run custom code when GAE fires up the instance; and
2. This `ThreadFactory`/`ThreadManager` stuff (above)
3. The servlets/listeners

I guess I'm wondering how to implement code such that every time a new request comes into, say, `FizzServlet#doGet`, how to make sure that request gets sent to an available thread (if there is one available). That way, if `FizzServlet` was the only servlet I was exposing, it could get called up to 10 times before it would cause a new (11th) incoming request to hang while a previous request was processing.

I'm looking for the glue code between the servlet and this thread-creating code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i don't quite see what the confusion is.  basically, you get the ThreadFactory from the ThreadManager and you launch a new Thread with your Runnable.  what more do you need to know?

Comment: @jtahlborn - with Threads and both the Factory and Manager classes, it's tough to tell which servlets will be serving which threads.

Comment: again, i'm not really following.  _each request_ has a limited number of threads it can spawn (and those threads must end before the request returns).  servlets have nothing (specific) to do with it as far as i can tell, and a servlet doesn't serve a thread...

Comment: Ah yes, but the servlet thread has a factory, and each factory has to be somehow wired (under the hood) to a GAE frontend or backend instace. I think that's where the problem is.

Comment: ...the problem in my question! (?!?!)

Comment: you have a request.  it creates one (or more) thread(s) using the factory.  there is a limit of 50 per request.  these threads run and complete before the request returns.  that's all there is to it.  as @JBNizet already mentioned, there's nothing else for you to _do_.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what @JBNizet explained, and now I understand that. I like to wait at least a day or two before I mark something as being the "definitive answer", but will most likely give him the "green check".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess I'm wondering how to implement code such that every time a new request comes into, say, FizzServlet#doGet, how to make sure that request gets sent to an available thread (if there is one available). That way, if FizzServlet was the only servlet I was exposing, it could get called up to 10 times before it would cause a new (11th) incoming request to hang while a previous request was processing.

That's what the GAE servlet engine does for you. You deploy an app containing a servlet, and when a request comes in, the servlet engine uses a thread to process the request and calls your servlet. You don't have anything to do.

If your servlet's `doGet()` or `doPost()` method, invoked by GAE, needs to perform several tasks in parallel (like contacting several other web sites for example), then you'll start threads by yourself as explained in the page you linked to.

Comment: Thanks @JB Nizet (+1) - so then can I always count on having up to 10 threads that my servlets can spawn, or could a "GAE thread" eat into this number? Thanks again.

Comment: Well, the documentation says you're limited to 50 concurrent request threads for each request. So in theory, you could start hundreds of threads if you only have 50 concurrent ones, and if all the threads complete before the request. But the [API doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/ThreadManager#currentRequestThreadFactory%28%29) also says that a runtime exception can be thrown if the thread creation took too long. I don't know more than what the documentation says.